# JavaScript object loses reference across functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am testing the SAPUI5 framework with a little todo list application. I have a database and access the data through a REST Service. I am able to get everything into my UI and from the UI into the database.

However, i am saving a reference of the database data in an JSON model which is mapped to a Table i am showing on the UI. When i try to add/delete elements, the writing to the database seem to work correctly but my intern model variable loses its reference between the different function calls ("initToDoModel" and "addToDo" for example). Here is the code:

```
  sap.ui.controller("sapui5_test.SAPUI5_Test", {

  //THIS IS THE REFFERENCE
  todoModel : null,            

        addTodo : function(text) {  
            this.doAjax("/add", {  
                text : text  
            }).done(function(todo) { 

                //HERE todoModel IS UNDEFINED BUT WAS SET IN initTodoModel
                this.todoModel.getProperty("/").push(todo); 
                this.todoModel.updateBindings();
                this.getView().rerender(); 
            });  
        },  

        initTodoModel : function() {    

            var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            var aData = jQuery.ajax({
                type : "GET",
                contentType : "application/json",
                url : "http://sapm04.ibsolution.local:50000/demo.sap.com~d337_resttest_web/rest/todo/init/",
                dataType : "json",
                async: false,
                success : function(data,textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    oModel.setData({modelData : data});

                    //HERE THE todoModel IS SET
                    this.todoModel = oModel;
                    alert("Ok");
                }

            });
            return oModel;
        },  

        doAjax : function(path, content, type, async) {  
            var params = {  
                url : "http://sapm04.ibsolution.local:50000/demo.sap.com~d337_resttest_web/rest/todo" + path,  
                dataType : "json",  
                contentType : "application/json",  
                context : this, 
                //async : false,
                cache : false  
            };  

            params["type"] = type || "POST";  

            if (async === false) {  
                params["async"] = async;  
            }  

            if (content) {  
                params["data"] = JSON.stringify(content);  
            }  

            return jQuery.ajax(params);  
        },  

        getTodo : function(id) {  
            var index, todo;  

            jQuery.each(this.todoModel.getProperty("/"), function(i, t) {  
                if (t.id === id) {  
                    index = i;  
                    todo = t;  
                }  
            });  

            return {  
                index : index,  
                todo : todo  
            };  
        }

    });
```

so the initToDoModel function is called every time the page is loaded, gets data from db, maps it into an JSONModel object. Then when i click the Add Button on my page the addToDo function is called and needs to update the cached JSONModel which is undefined by this time.

I am new to JavaScript so maybe someone could explain what is happening there.

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is. Store it in another variable and use that variable instead.

Comment: If you're interested in a little more detail of the behaviour of this in JavaScript check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `console.log(this);` inside of your AJAX callback - you'll probably see that it references the `window` object.

You can maintain a reference to the current object by storing the desired context for `this` in a variable before your AJAX call.

```
addTodo : function(text) {  
        var that = this;
        this.doAjax("/add", {  
            text : text  
        }).done(function(todo) { 

            //HERE todoModel IS UNDEFINED BUT WAS SET IN initTodoModel
            that.todoModel.getProperty("/").push(todo); 
            that.todoModel.updateBindings();
            that.getView().rerender(); 
        });  
    },
```